# What is a word for “once filled with water”?

Tags: word-request

Imagine geologists in an undiscovered location looking at a crater. Because of some erosion they theorize this crater was “xxx” or once filled with water.
A canister with mineral deposits on the edge. “Oh this is must be a xxx container”

Comment: Might be better to ask a geologist TBH.  I think the word you might be looking for is an "aquifer" but I am not a geologist.

Comment: Thank you, maby i will try lol. I don’t quite think the word would be aquifer as it would be more descriptive. Like describing the schema of a place that once held water specifying the past nature of it. Dry, cracked, dehydrated, etc. area that used to hold water. Could be an empty pool, jug, plant, place.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence (actually more of a noun phrase than a full sentence): "A used canister with mineral deposits on the edge." Why was the canister used? Why is it on the edge of crater? Why are the mineral deposits important?

Comment: @BenjaminGoldin Can you explain a bit about why you are confident this specific word exists? Does a similar word exist in another language you know, or did you once know it and have forgotten?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I edited the sentence but it would be to show the nature of water being once present if that makes sense.

Comment: To @Katy  I read something similar in translation of the torah, and it was one word in Hebrew.I have been looking for the passage but I can’t seem to find it as I saw it roughly 3 years ago.

Comment: I doubt such a word exists in everyday English. It will be a specialist word if it does exist, so maybe try in [earthscience.se].

Comment: You might look at some sites discussing hydrated minerals, such as those found on Mars, to look for descriptive language. See https://sci.esa.int/web/mars-express/-/51821-1-hydrated-minerals-ndash-evidence-of-liquid-water-on-mars or https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2019JE006351 .

Comment: You may be looking for the word **evaporated**.  For example, *The water in the glass evaporated over the course of the summer.*  Evaporation, however, is just one of many ways that water can leave a container.

Comment: If this is from a bible verse then perhaps you could give some more hint about which book.  For example there is the line in Bereshit about the waters of the flood.  That word is usually translated as "dried up".

Comment: That word would be יְבֹ֥שֶׁת in hebrew

Comment: "Dried up" might work depending on context, although it doesn't indicate the type or amount of water (whether a bit damp or full to the brim). Certainly as suggested above reading [Water on Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_on_Mars) doesn't have any suitable terms - there may be words for specific features (e.g. a wadi is a dried water channel in the desert) but a not general term for all objects.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the phrase "once filled with water" - that seems to be the most natural expression.

The name of flat basins, usually in deserts, that were once lakes is "playa".  A playa is a location where ephemeral lakes form during wet periods, and is underlain by stratified clay, silt, and sand, and commonly, soluble salts.([source](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2004/1007/playas.html))

Comment: I'm upvoting in support of the statement that there's nothing wrong with using the phrase "once filled with water" to express this idea. It seems like the OP is looking for an adjective, so while the descriptions are related, I'm not sure that playa/aquifer/caldera and the like are appropriate answers.

Answer (score -4):

caldera

> A caldera is a large depression formed when a volcano erupts and
> collapses. During a volcanic eruption, magma present in the magma
> chamber underneath the volcano is expelled, often forcefully. When the
> magma chamber empties, the support that the magma had provided inside
> the chamber disappears. As a result, the sides and top of the volcano
> collapse inward. Calderas vary in size from one to 100 kilometers
> (0.62 to 62 miles) in diameter.
>
> **Some calderas form a lake** as the bowl-shaped depression fills with
> water. A famous example is Crater Lake, in Oregon.

[National Geographic](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/calderas/)

Comment: A caldera is a crater formed when a magma chamber collapses, it may or may not contain a lake,  doesn't mean "Once filled with water".

Comment: "they theorize this crater was “xxx” or once filled with water" i.e. it was once a caldera with water.

Comment: That doesn't work.  If you say "They theorize this crater was a caldera" it doesn't mean that it was once filled with water.  A caldera isn't something that was once filled with water.

Comment: @JamesK A caldera filled with water. I said: a caldera with water or filled with water a water-filled caldera.

Comment: That makes no sense.  Why mention "caldera" at all?  Why not just say "a crater that was once filled with water"?   This doesn't answer the question, as it doesn't give a word or phrase that means "was once filled with water".

Comment: @Because it is not a canister, that's why. And erosion was mentioned, could have just been a cave in. Yours doesn't answer it either, and does like mine as far as repeating filled with water goes...